# find conditional probability from marginal probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have expressions for marginal probability distributions p(a) and p(b). The joint probability distribution p(a,b), if I understood correctly, can be obtained by the product p(a)*p(b). I need to find the conditional probability P(Y|a,b). What information about Y is needed for doing this? If the probability distribution of Y is simply given as p(Y), what would be the expression for conditional probability?

Comment: What is Y in terms of a and b?

Comment: p(A=a,B=b) =  p(A=a)*p(B=b) only if A and B are independent.

Comment: I am trying to understand the theory behind a specific mathematical derivation, so I am not yt sure what is Y in terms of a and b, but assuming p(Y) is known simply as p(Y) and p(a,b) = p(a)*p(b), what should be done to get P(Y|a,b)? Or is the given data not enough to determine this conditional probability?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to find the conditional probability $P(Y|a,b)$. What information about $Y$ is needed for doing this?

One way or another, the joint distribution of $(Y,a,b)$.